# connection failed

Tags: download

I am trying to call the below URL from python script:

https://api.fda.gov/download.json

but it gives the below error message:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.fda.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /download.json?api_key=API_KEY (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcc062a4908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

Kindly suggest

Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: This may be a question better suited to Stack Overflow if you provide the Python script you are using. Also I'm not sure if the API keys are free but its best not to disclose your API key, or maybe you changed it to a different value to post?

Comment: Hi we are simply passing the URL in python requests.get(URL, verify=False) method and got the above error everytime

Comment: Also is there any possibility that FDA ie api.fda.gov is blocking our request??